# Table: How to make a table with blank lines

Tags: tables

I need a table with blank lines for my Lab reports, If I write a normal table I get lines that are too small, I searched the internet and what I found was a table here with the following code ( slightly altered ): ( Need Horizontal spacing )

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash $}X<{$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\rule[-4ex]{0pt}{7ex}}|*{12}{C|}}
\hline
\Delta d (cm) & 0 & 0.5 & 1 & 1.5 & 2 & 2.5 & 3 & 3.5 & 4 & 4.5 & 5 \\
\hline
y_R & & & & & & & & & & \\
\Delta ( \Delta d ) (mm) & & & & & & & & & & \\ [0.5ex]
\hline \hline
\Delta d (cm ) & 5.5 & 6 & 6.5 & 7 & 7.5 & 8 & 8.5 & 9 & 9.5 & 10\\
\hline
y_R & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
\Delta ( \Delta d ) (mm) & & & & & & & & & &\\ [0.5 ex]
\hline \hline
\Delta d (cm) & 10.5 & 11 & 11.5 & 12 &12.5 & 13 & 13.5 & 14 & 14.5\\
y_R & & & & & & & & & & \\
\Delta ( \Delta d ) (mm) & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Three points on this one :

- If I don't use the center environment more than half the table will get out of the page
- No lines in between the rows
- The last lines are half blank

I use ShareLatex at the moment, so don't know if it can do any bad, Local Tex editor makes my equations  go crazy.

EDIT: Issue Fixed, the last lines being half blank was due to the table being wider than the maximum ( I thought it would just reduce it ) But apparently due to the code I found, the width is set, and overrid Latex's compiler. reducing the table's collumns number to 11 fixed it. Though the extra table that contains the other values is ugly. And if I reduce the table size more I will have to make 4 tables, which is not very pretty.

Comment: Have you tried the `array` package and its option to increase spacing (`arraystretch`)?

Comment: Should've made it more clear, The issue is the horizontal spacing rather than the vertical spacing. `arraystretch` works on Vertical spacing if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Okay, I was not aware that your question refers to the horizontal space. Good you edited it.

Comment: Another question: Why don't you use a fixed-width (`p`) column type to make the horizontal spacing match your needs?

Comment: Are you, basically, asking how to make the first column wider?

Comment: I'm asking how to make wide empty columns, and no ugly half blank lines in the right end. And lines in between the lines, since I don't see them.

Comment: Edit : Fixed the invisible lines, turns out I'm not concentrating now. Not the half invisible right side though, didn't fix it.

Comment: Your write-up remains rather confusing, I'm afraid. E.g.,, what exactly did you do to "fix the invisible lines"?

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what is your problem, however your number of ampersands are n many rows to small. Also suggest to remove math environments from column definition and locally set math if it is necessary. After this changes I obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\rule[-4ex]{0pt}{7ex}} |*{12}{C|}}
\hline
$\Delta d$ (cm)
        & 0   & 0.5 & 1  & 1.5 & 2   & 2.5 & 3  & 3.5 & 4    & 4.5 & 5  \\
\hline
$y_R$   &     &     &    &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &    \\
$\Delta$ $(\Delta d)$ (mm) 
        &     &     &    &     &     &     &     &     &     &     &    \\ [0.5ex]
\hline \hline
$\Delta d$ (cm) 
        & 5.5 & 6   & 6.5 & 7  & 7.5 & 8   & 8.5 & 9   & 9.5 & 10  &    \\
\hline
$y_R$   &     &     &     &    &     &     &     &      &    &     &    \\
\hline
$\Delta$ $(\Delta d)$ (mm) 
        &     &     &     &    &     &     &     &      &     &    &    \\ [0.5 ex]
\hline \hline
$\Delta d$ (cm) 
        & 10.5& 11  & 11.5& 12 &12.5 & 13  & 13.5& 14   & 14.5&    &    \\
$y_R$   &     &     &     &    &     &     &     &      &     &    &    \\
$\Delta$ $(\Delta d)$ (mm) 
        &     &     &     &    &     &     &     &      &     &    &    \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, if you like to have first column wider, replace the first `C` with `l`:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\rule[-4ex]{0pt}{7ex}} |l|*{11}{C|}}
```

And you will obtain:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the use of `\rule`!